# Group by and filter multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a result set from a stored procedure (using Linq).

The returned data looks like this:

```
+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
| Customer| Item | Week1 | Week2 | Week3 | Week4 |  
+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
| A       |    1 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |  
| A       |    2 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |  
| B       |    1 | NULL  | M     | NULL  | NULL  |  
| B       |    2 | M     | NULL  | E     | NULL  |  
| C       |    1 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |  
| C       |    2 | M     | NULL  | NULL  | M     |  
+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm trying to filter out customers that have NULL across all week columns for all items. In this case, I'd like to filter out the rows for customer A, but list all rows and columns for customers B and C. The full result set will be several hundred customers and several thousand items.

I've gotten as far as grouping the data together, but I'm having trouble with actually removing the items  that I don't want.

```
custEvents.GroupBy(
ce => new
{
    custId = ce.companyID,
    week1 = ce.wk1eventId,
    week2 = ce.wk2eventId,
    week3 = ce.wk3eventId,
    week4 = ce.wk4eventId
}
).OrderBy(ce => ce.Key.custId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var customers = data.Where(c => c.Week1 != null || c.Week2 != null || c.Week3 != null || c.Week4 != null).Select(c => c.CustomerId);
var filteredResult = data.Where(c => customers.Contains(c.CustomerId));
```

Comment: He wants to filter those that have ALL those properties as null, not ANY of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to group by Customer and get the groups that have any non-null week records:

```
custEvents.GroupBy(c => c.Customer)
          .Where(g => g.Any(c => c.wk1eventId != null || c.wk2eventId != null || c.wk3eventId != null || c.wk4eventId != null))
          .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could always remove after you have ordered it.

```
custEvents.RemoveAll(x => x.Customer = "A" && x.week1 = null && x.week2 = null && x.week3 = null && x.week4 = null);
```

Comment: They're going to be waisting CPU cycles ordering elements they don't need.

Comment: I would do it the way you have answered, but I was just providing another alternative as the OP has already ordered it